# AudioKit Playground Builds fail

Tags: swift, xcode, audiokit

I'm new to Xcode and I've decided to use AudioKit for the sound of my apps, so I'm starting to try out all of the functions through the AudioKit playground. When ever I try to run any of the AudioKit playground examples, the build fails and brings me 2704 issues and most of them just say 'x' is not a member of 'y'

[image: error image]

Comment: Hi there, im not sure if you are doing the right thing on Play Ground. You are following some tutorial ou documentation ?

Comment: Right now i'm tying different ways to download it. I got the no such module 'AudioKit' error by following the tutorial, so now i'm trying to download the AudioKit through cocoapods. I will let you know if it will work for me.

Comment: Heres my update so far, I've tried playground the tutorial way and that still didn't work, so I tried to move on to the AudioKit-*.zip download and followed the https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/tree/master/Frameworks/README.md instructions. Once I ran the project it said no module 'AudioKit', so I looked at other posts and did their solution but that just brought me a different error(Failed to load module'AudioKit'). After that failed attempt, I tried to download AudioKit through cocoapods and it said the same error as before(Failed to load module'AudioKit')

Comment: Try to use on your app, not PlayGround and see if it works. Try to clean your cache, try to create a empty project with only this AudioKit. Keep trying. And let us know

Comment: Does the AudioKit 4.95 only works for the newest update of Xcode?

Comment: After searching the internet I think I found out whats the problem from this website(https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/2017). Im using Xcode 11.3.1 and the 4.9.5 AudioKit was created for Xcode 11.4, but I cant upgrade my Xcode since my computer doesn't has enough storage for the Catalina update.